# Need a SQL query to select people within a specific age limit based on the current date

Tags: sql

How to select people within age limit 19 t0 25 if the current date is less than '2011-01-01'
and age limit between 19 to 26 if the current date is greater than or equal to'2011-01-01'

Comment: What's your table structure, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple AND-OR logic to acheive this.

```
Select * from <people_table>
  where ( (age between 19 and 25) and 
            (current_date < to_date('2011-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
        )
     or (  (age between 19 and 26) and 
           (current_date >= to_date('2011-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
        )
```

Unless of course, by current_date, if you mean sysdate, you'll have...

```
Select * from <people_table>
  where ( (age between 19 and 25) and 
            (sysdate < to_date('2011-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
        )
     or (  (age between 19 and 26) and 
           (sysdate >= to_date('2011-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in MySQL, CURDATE() will get you the current date.
Then, you could sue DATEDIFF() and see if the difference is in a range you want. 
For example,

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATEDIFF(year,CURDATE(),date) > 18 AND DATEDIFF(year, CURDATE(), date) < 26;

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
select * from people_table
    where age > 19 and age <= 
    case 
    when (getdate() < '2011-01-01') then 25
    when (getdate() >= '2011-01-01') then 26
    end
```